# Vue.js use variable within a component in another component

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js

I've got an employee table. Every employee has a role, I'm trying to filter that with radio buttons (for example a radio button admin or superadmin).

How can I use a variable within a component in another component? Right now I've this:

```
   <template id="searchemployees">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Filter</label>

            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="radio radio-primary">
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="intern" id="intern" value="intern" v-model="selectedrole"/>
                        Toon alles
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="radio radio-primary">
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="employee" id="employee" value="employee" v-model="selectedrole">
                        Stagiaire
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>    
        </div>
    </template>

 <template id="employees">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Logo</th>
                <th>Bedrijfsnaam</th>
                <th>Plaats</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr class="table-row-link" data-href="" v-for="employee in list | role selectedrole">
                    <td><img class="img-circle-company" src=""/></td>
                    <td>@{{ employee.role.RoleName }}</td>
                    <td>@{{ employee.LastName }}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </template>

<script>
        Vue.config.debug = true;

        Vue.filter('role',function(value,role)
        {
            if(!role || 0 === role.length)
            {
                return value;
            }
            return value.filter(function(item) {
                return item.role.RoleName == role
            });
        });

        Vue.component('searchemployees', {
            template: '#searchemployees'
        });

        Vue.component('employees', {
            template: '#employees',
            props:['list'],
            created() {
                this.list = JSON.parse(this.list);
            }
        });

        new Vue({
            el: 'body'
        });
</script>
```

In my `#searchemployees`it takes the right selected role. But how can I use it in `#employees` for my filter?

Thankyou

Comment: What variable are you trying to pass between your components? I'm assuming it's `props:['list']` ?

Comment: @10000RubyPools Actually I want the list item to be global so I can acces it from any component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to send a property from a component upwards to the root / global Vue instance by dispatching an event. Dispatching an event means you're sending a message, one that contains a property, to a component's parent in the Vue tree. You dispatch an event using the following syntax:

```
this.$dispatch('event-name', this.list);
```

This says, send an event with an ID of `event-name`, containing the property `this.list`, to the component's parent.

Your component's parent can only receive this dispatched property if it is listening for that exact message with the ID of `event-name`. You can listen to events from within the parent component using the following code (this goes in parent):

```
events: {
    'event-name': function(property) {
        console.log("Property from child component" + property);
    }
}
```

Overall, your code should look something like this:

```
Vue.component('employees', {
    template: '#employees',
    props:['list'],
    created() {
        this.list = JSON.parse(this.list);
        this.$dispatch('send-list', this.list);
    }
});

new Vue({
    el: 'body',
    data: {
        rootlist: {}
    },
    events: {
        'send-list': function(property) {
            this.rootlist = property;
            console.log("Property from child component" + property);
        }
    }
});
```

This will make all of your `[list]` data available within your root Vue instance. If you'd like to send it down to all components, you can create a broadcast event `this.$broadcast('send-list-down', this.list);` within the `send-list` function. `$broadcast` does the exact same thing as `$dispatch`, but it sends the data down the Vue tree instead of up. Just make sure you create event listeners within your components and for the `send-list-down` event.

Comment: Thanks! You explained it well.