# Vue.js use v-on:click with a radiobutton

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How can I use `$dispatch()` or `$broadcast()` on a radio button? I can't do something like this (because I cannot use `v-on:click` on a radio button):

**HTML**

```
 <div class="radio radio-primary">
     <label>
         <input type="radio" name="intern" id="intern" value="intern" 
                v-on:click="update" v-model="selectedrole"/>
             Showall
      </label>                          
</div>
```

**JS**

```
Vue.component('searchemployees', {
    template: '#searchemployees',
    data: function()
    {
        return {
            selectedrole: ''
        }
    },
    methods: {
        update: function()
        {
            this.$dispatch('selectedRole', this.selectedrole)
        }
    }
});

Vue.component('employees', {
    template: '#employees',
    props:['list'],
    data: function()
    {
        return {
            role: ''
        }
    },
    created() {
        this.list = JSON.parse(this.list);
    },
    events: {
        'selectedrole': function(role) {
            this.role = role
        }
    }
});
```

Because I can't use `v-on:click` on a radio button. How can I do this? (I need selectedrole in 2 components).

Some  help please!

Comment: This seems to be you asking your original question in a different way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35727169/vue-js-use-variable-within-a-component-in-another-component .  You should have just updated your original question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can broadcast the event whenever `selectedrole` changes using `watch`:

```
Vue.component('searchemployees', {
  template: '#searchemployees',
  data: function()
    {
      return {
        selectedrole: ''
      }
    },
    watch: {
      selectedrole: function(newRole)
      {
        this.$dispatch('selectedRole', newRole)
      }
    }
});
```

Then just remove the click listener, it isn't needed